# How to create a firebase rule to allow creating a child node with the same name as $uid as soon as user signs up

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

```py
def sign_up(email, password):
    # create user node with UID under NGO
    user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
    uid = user['localId']
    db.child("NGO").child(uid).set({
        'email': email
    })
    return user
if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = {
    # API config
    }
    firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
    db = firebase.database()
    auth = firebase.auth()
    user = sign_up(email, password)
```

Now to make this code work, the only solution I have come up with so far is

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "NGO": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": true,
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This approach unfortunately gives write access to the entire NGO node to any $uid

What did not work (it can't create a new node named $uid itself but can read/write if it already exists) -

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "NGO": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The RTDB structure looks like this

[image]

Comment: That second example should work, as (even when you *first* write the `$uid` node) the `$uid` will match `auth.uid`. If you get a permission error on it, you might want to log the `uid` value in yoru code right before you use it to write to the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for responding but i am recieving `[Errno 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:` error when trying to create node $uid.

Comment: Hmm... that doesn't read like a Firebase error at first glance. That'd normally give a very explicit "Permission denied", like you can see here: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/youcantreadthisnode.json --- Did you log the `uid` value already?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes I did log the uid value already